# Android(version 4.1) emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

Recently I have decided to start developing mobile apps for android. I installed 4.1 - version of Android SDK.

When I start the emulator I just got black screen and nothing starts. I have chosen different settings but nothing else is happening. My computer is running Ubuntu 10.04, 256 MB Ram, 1Ghz processor, 32 MB Video card.

I know this is not normal computer for these days. So I notice that when I make new AVD on Eclipse indigo ram is set to 512MB so this is my question:

Is this the problem and if it is, please help me solving it? (will everything be alright if I install different version of android).

Give me suggestions for solving it. I am praying for starting the AVD.

Comment: Did you check your ram usage while running your application? I think your ram is not sufficient. I had 1GB ram still was not able to run properly.

Comment: Android 4.1 emulator is heavyweight. You should really try it in a faster computer.

Comment: In my way the emulator doesn't start. Just black screen.

Comment: @Nikalas1111 It start what you are calling black screen shows that it is started but it is running out of RAM so no further thread is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the recommended [system requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). 256 MB RAM is way too low. Seriously, my phone has more RAM :)

Comment: OK. But is there way of running it. I know that 256MB ram are low.

Comment: for example running android version 2.3

Comment: For all practical purposes - no. The emulator takes a good one minute to load on my computer. I have 8GB RAM.